# Looking for memory leaks in my Node.js app

Tags: node.js, express, memory-leaks, node-inspector

Monitoring my node.js app showed me an increasing consumption of RAM.

So I started to look into the code and do multiple tests but I can't figure out how to correct those leaks and where exactly they're coming from.

To test and look at the memory leaks, I'm running my app with
`node --expose-gc --inspect index.js`

In my index.js :

```js
setInterval(() => {
  // 1. Force garbage collection every time this function is called
  try {
    global.gc();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("You must run program with 'node --expose-gc index.js' or 'npm start'");
    process.exit();
  }
  const { rss, heapUsed, heapTotal } = process.memoryUsage();
  console.log(
    'rss',
    numeral(rss).format('0.0 ib'),
    'heapUsed',
    numeral(heapUsed).format('0.0 ib'),
    'heapTotal',
    numeral(heapTotal).format('0.0 ib'),
  );
}, 5000);
```

I can clearly see the heap growing after any action on my app
[terminal heap screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGGQB.png)

With the node inspector I take multiple screenshot and compare them but I don't see anything related to my own code ([memory leak which seems to come from moment.js (I don't have anything called "guesses" in my code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Puq63.png)). Like if all my leaks were coming from dependencies (I did `yarn upgrade --latest`)

It would really help me if someone could take a look at 3 of my heap snapshots to help me find out the source of my memory leaks

Comment: May I ask why are you forcing the garbage collector to run? I recently rewrote a codebase of mine, so that I never force call garbage collector(I used to recently). And also, whenever you call garbage collector, for a certain while when it is running, memory usage would increase.

Comment: This is the first time I'm working on memory leaks and in some tutorials, they were advising to do it like that but ok I'm gonna try without it

Comment: OK I removed it and did tests again -> same result, same heap increase

Comment: Yes, well even I am not well versed in memory leak situations. I thought that would do it.